# Run Apache Tomcat as user "tomcat"

Tags: tomcat, user-accounts

I want to run Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu 18 as the (by me created) user `tomcat`.

I am not using the Ubuntu default Tomcat but instead directly downloaded the tar.gz package from the Tomcat homepage.

I have installed it in `/opt`.

For security reasons I want to run the tomcat a user `tomcat` which I created in the following way:

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false tomcat
```

Now, I would like to start tomcat using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/su -s /bin/bash -c "/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh" tomcat
```

When I run this script I get the following output:

```
ubuntu@server-8x32:/opt/tomcat/bin$ ./start-tomcat.sh 
Password:
```

I did not specify a password and since this script is also called from some other automatically executed script I cannot provide a password each time.

So my question is: How do I start Apache Tomcat as the user `tomcat` without being prompt to enter a password?

Comment: Modify /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `tomcat` group and this file at `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` with the contents:

```
#Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking


Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start the service with

```
systemctl start tomcat
```

That will run the service as `tomcat`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I found an very nice explanation for this systemd service file here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files